# CNN or Viola-Jones for facial detection

Tags: convolutional-neural-network

I was wondering since CNNs have dominated every image-related task. Is the Viola-Jones face detector still considered state-of-the-art, or have CNNs surpassed its performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the paper [A Comparison of CNN-based Face and Head Detectors for
Real-Time Video Surveillance Applications](https://www.etsmtl.ca/Unites-de-recherche/LIVIA/Recherche-et-innovation/Publications/Publications-2017/Thanh_IPTA17_v5fin.pdf) CNN based neural networks are significantly better than Viola-Jones in terms of precision but need more computational power to calculate the results. The mean average precision error for CNN based networks is 5 times less than for VJ for FDDB data. Here is the precision comparison table from the paper:

[image: Precision comparison table]

But VJ allows real time recognition with 60 frames per second. Here is the speed comparison from the same paper:

[image: Speed comparison table]